# How to make a command global/static?

Tags: linux, command

When using commands such as cat, they don't require for a path to be executed. How can this be done in Linux?

Comment: Shell parses `$PATH` and finds all executables files in it, that's how `cat` is run. Your question doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: What have you researched/searched for? This is a very basic thing almost any web pages about a Unix/Unix-like operating system should cover in detail.

Answer (score 1):

The `$PATH` variable contains a colon-separated list of directories to search for commands. See `echo "$PATH"` for one way of viewing its value. On my systems for my own login I include `$HOME/bin` at the beginning of the `$PATH`, and this is where I put my own utilities and scripts

Example

```
mkdir "$HOME/bin"
cat >"$HOME/bin/thing" <<'EOF'
#!/bin/bash
echo this is the thing
exit 0
EOF
chmod a+x "$HOME/bin/thing"

[ -d "$HOME/bin" ] && export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"    # XX
```

Demonstration

```
thing                # run this as a command
this is the thing    # program output
```

If you like this idea, add the line tagged `XX` to your `.bash_profile` or `.profile`